# Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'database.order.oid' isn't in GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, laravel

Below is my sql code which is working properly

```
SELECT oid, date(ordered_on) AS ord, count(date(ordered_on)) AS cnt
FROM order
GROUP BY ord DESC
LIMIT 10
```

But when i apply it in laravel, I am not able to evaluate the result. Below is the laravel code

```
DB::table('order')
            ->select(DB::raw('oid, date(ordered_on) as ord, count(date(ordered_on)) as cnt'))
            ->groupBy('ord')
            ->orderBy('oid', 'desc')
            ->limit(10)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your raw MySQL query should ideally not be working, because it doesn't make much sense.  I sense that what you want to do is get a count of records by date.  If so, then you want this query:

```
SELECT DATE(ordered_on), COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM `order`
GROUP BY DATE(ordered_on);
```

This would imply the following Laravel code:

```
DB::table('order')
    ->select(DB::raw('DATE(ordered_on) AS ord, COUNT(*) AS cnt'))
        ->groupBy('ord')
        ->orderBy('ord', 'desc')
        ->limit(10)
        ->get();
```

By the way, don't name your tables, columns, etc. using reserved MySQL keywords like `order`.  I needed to escape `order` in my query, and you will need to do the same, perpetually, moving forward.

Comment: Thanks..Sure sir :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are using strict mode in laravel. By the you can tweak it to your needs.

got to `config/database.php`  in set `strict=>false` and you are good to go.

```
  'mysql' => [
          // ....

            'strict' => false
        ],
```

Comment: This might be throwing out the baby with the bathwater though. MySQL's strict mode offers a lot. It might be worth just disabling the specific settings you are not interested in using.

Comment: This worked but I want to keep the strict mode to true